# spark job which write parquet data to hive has stuck in the last task when parquet use Snappy algorithm rather than gzip

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, snappy

I'm writing a parquet file from DataFrame to Hive. When I use snappy as parquet compression algorithm, I can see all tasks but 1 completed swiftly of the writing stage (e.g. 30/31). This last task takes long time to complete because of lots of gc process.

And when I use gzip as parquet compression algorithm, everything will be ok.

I'd like to know what is differences of two compression algorithms.

Comment: the problem happened only when I use spark2.1.0。

Answer (score 1):

**gzip** is naturally supported by **Hadoop**. gzip is based on the DEFLATE **algorithm**, which is a combination of **LZ77 and Huffman Coding**.

**GZIP compression** uses **more CPU resources** than **Snappy**, but provides a higher compression ratio.

**GZip** is often a **good** choice for **cold data**, which is accessed **infrequently**.

**Snappy** are a better choice for hot data, which is **accessed frequently**.

**Snappy** formats are **splittable**, but **GZip** is not. Splittability is not relevant to HBase data.

Reference:
 [Data Compression in Hadoop](http://comphadoop.weebly.com/)